# How to fetch details of non-leader models generated by h2o automl?

Tags: h2o, automl

after running `automl` (classification of 3 classes), I can see a list of models as follows:

`model_id                                                mean_per_class_error
StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_0_AutoML_20180420_174925   0.262355
StackedEnsemble_AllModels_0_AutoML_20180420_174925      0.262355
XRT_0_AutoML_20180420_174925                            0.266606
DRF_0_AutoML_20180420_174925                            0.278428
GLM_grid_0_AutoML_20180420_174925_model_0               0.442917`

but `mean_per_class_error` is not a good metric for my case, where classes are unbalanced (one class has very small population). How to fetch details of non-leader models and calculate other metrics? Thanks.

python version: 3.6.0

h2o version:    3.18.0.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually just figured this out myself (assuming `aml` is the h2o automl object after training):

`for m in aml.leaderboard.as_data_frame()['model_id']:
    print(m)
    print(h2o.get_model(m))`

Answer (score 4):

You can also grab the corresponding model you're interested in using the following line:

`model6 = h2o.get_model(aml.leaderboard.as_data_frame()['model_id'][6])`

where 6 is the index number of the model in the leaderboard.